# update one data frame with values of other data frame based on the column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

update the data frame with another data frame value.
based on date same date value of the second data frame update the first data frame

```
df1 = [

date            value 1     value 2
5/12/2021       6.7         8.9
5/13/2021       7.4         6.9
5/14/2021       8.3         9.5
5/15/2021       8.7         9.6

]
```

```
df2 = [

date         value 1        value 2
5/13/2021    9.4            8.9
5/14/2021    8.6            9.3

]
```

output data frame

```
df_out = [
date         value 1        value 2
5/12/2021       6.7         8.9
5/13/2021       9.4         8.9
5/14/2021       8.6         9.3
5/15/2021       8.7         9.6
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.set_index()` to "date" column and then [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas-dataframe-update):

```py
df1 = df1.set_index("date")
df1.update(df2.set_index("date"))
print(df1.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
        date  value 1  value 2
0  5/12/2021      6.7      8.9
1  5/13/2021      9.4      8.9
2  5/14/2021      8.6      9.3
3  5/15/2021      8.7      9.6
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first) option:

```py
new_df = df2.set_index('date') \
    .combine_first(df1.set_index('date')) \
    .reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

```
        date  value 1  value 2
0  5/12/2021      6.7      8.9
1  5/13/2021      9.4      8.9
2  5/14/2021      8.6      9.3
3  5/15/2021      8.7      9.6
```